# Finding smallest contiguous integers in a Python set

Tags: python, set

What is the best way to get a list of the smallest N contiguous integers in a Python set?

```
>>> s=set([5,6,10,12,13,15,30,40,41,42,43,44,55,56,90,300,500])
>>> s
set([42, 43, 44, 5, 6, 90, 300, 30, 10, 12, 13, 55, 56, 15, 500, 40, 41])
>>> smallest_contiguous(s,5)
[40,41,42,43,44]
>>> smallest_contiguous(s,6)
[]
```

Edit: Thanks for the answers, everyone.

Comment: sort and check diff to be 1 on n items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sven has the right idea. You can avoid having to check supersets by just checking the number N - 1 ahead.

```
def smallest_contiguous(s, N):
    lst = list(s)
    lst.sort()
    Nm = N-1
    for i in xrange(len(lst) - Nm):
        if lst[i] + Nm == lst[i + Nm]:
            return range(lst[i], lst[i]+N)
    return []
```

This will only always be correct for a set as input and knowing that the set only contains integers.

Comment: Nice :)  Should be `xrange(len(lst) - Nm)` I think.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
def smallest_contiguous(s, N):
    lst = sorted(s)
    for i in lst:
        t = range(i, i+N)
        if s.issuperset(t):
            return t
    return []
```

It might not be the most efficient solution, but it is concise.

Edit: Justin's approach could also be made more concise:

```
def smallest_contiguous(s, N):
    lst = sorted(s)
    for a, b in zip(lst, lst[N - 1:]):
        if b - a == N - 1:
            return range(a, b + 1)
    return []
```

Answer (score 2):

That should do it ... look ahead `length - 1` steps in the sorted list. Since it contains integers only and is sorted, the difference must be `length - 1` as well.

```
def smallest_contiguous(myset, length):
    if len(myset) < length:
        return []

    s = sorted(myset)
    for idx in range(0, len(myset) - length + 1):
        if s[idx+length-1] - s[idx] == length - 1:
            return s[idx:idx+length]

    return []

s=set([5,6,10,12,13,15,30,40,41,42,43,44,55,56,90,300,500])
print smallest_contiguous(s, 5)
print smallest_contiguous(s, 6)
```

Comment: This code actually has the same off-by-one error as Justin's code originally had.  Should be `for idx in range(0, len(myset) - length + 1)`.

Comment: You're right, thx. Edited. Too many +/- 1's in the code anyway ... one more now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I came up with:

```
def smallest_contiguous(s,N):
    try:
        result = []
        while len(result) < N:
            min_value = min(s)
            s.remove(min_value)
            if result == [] or min_value == result[-1] + 1:
                result.append(min_value)
            else:
                result = [min_value]
        return result
    except ValueError:
        return []
```

It modifies the input set as a side effect.

Comment: This will iterate the whole remaining set in each iteration, so it is O(n^2).  But of course it works.

Comment: @Sven, I'm not sure what you mean. It stops when it finds the contiguous block of sufficient length.

Comment: Yes, it works fine.  I'm talking about [algorithmic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_complexity): for big sets, this algorithm is far less efficient than any of the others.

Answer (score 0):

itertools to the rescue. groupby does all the grunt work here
The algorithm is O(n logn) because of the call to `sorted()`

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, count
>>> def smallest_contiguous(s, N):
...     for i,j in groupby(sorted(s), key=lambda i,c=count().next: i-c()):
...         res = list(j)
...         if len(res) == N:
...             return res
...     return []

... 
>>> smallest_contiguous(s,5)
[40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
>>> smallest_contiguous(s,6)
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def smallest_contiguous(s, n):
    xs = sorted(s)
    return next(x for i, x in enumerate(xs) if xs[i + n - 1] == x + n - 1)
```